# IS there a .Net Publish/Subscribe Framework

Tags: .net, publish-subscribe

I am looking for a Publish/Subscribe framework in .net. My goal is to have clients dynamically register/deregister to receive certain messages. Then a message queue processor dequeue and send appropriate messages to the clients. I would like to find something that is already built, so I don't have to build out all the system mamangement this will require. Any suggestions ? Blogs that would describe something like this. Azure Appfabric might be what I am looking for, but evertyinthing I am finding is very low level. I am looking for a nearly complete framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/) (http://nservicebus.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In our research project, we've recently developed a .net based, completely distributed middleware called Ella. It performs automatic discovery in the network based on UDP broadcasts.
You can find it at http://ella.codeplex.com